Material not showing properly in aframe when imported from blender
I made a model in Blender, it has several different objects with different materials. when i export it in glb format and try to import it in a-frame the models appear and their materials also appear but the materials like glossy are just colors they are not shinning as they were in Blender material preview. So, how can i import these materials properly into a-frame or are there any settings i need to change while exporting them from Blender??
